# Snapping while measure in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, snapping

I've been reading here and there that snapping while measuring should work in QGIS, but i can not make it work for the life of me.
https://hub.qgis.org/issues/8537

All the snapping options are set correctly in the snapping option dialog box (and they snap just fine while digitizing), but i don't get a snap while measuring.

Any idea's where i need to look?

Answer (score 5):

The snapping has moved for QGIS3.

`Project  Snapping Options...` to display the Project Snapping Settings toolbar:

[image]

Then you need to toggle on the snapping and away you go!
[[image]

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't work for Azimuth Measurement.

Answer (score 1):

Under Settings > Snapping Options

Choose the snapping mode (which layers you want to snap to)

Choose what to 'snap to' (vertex, segment, etc.)

Choose the tolerance you want to use for snapping (I set it to 2 map units just to test)

Click 'OK' to set those properties and close the Snapping Options window

Now use the Measure tool and you should see the vertices of the measurement (lines, in my test case) snap to the layers / vertices /segments you have just set.